# How to know the Duration of audio song before streaming?

Tags: android, streaming, media-player

I am making an application for Stream audio song. In Custom media player, i have to show the total duration of that audio file.
If a audio song will be SDCard , i can know its duration using

```
MediaPlayer player;

public double duration() {
        return player.getDuration();
    }
```

But in my case audio file is on the server, so i have to stream it.

What is the best approach?

Comment: check [this][1] it may help you in finding lenght and duration of media file


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13162180/1447595

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This might help you: [Example of Streaming mp3 with android media player class](http://www.hrupin.com/2011/02/27/example-of-streaming-mp3-mediafile-with-android-mediaplayer-class) .
The respective data is probably available, once prepare() is called for the file to be streamed.

Comment: it doesnt work on android 2.3. any idea what can be the reason?

Comment: @rachit: Can you tell what exactly is happening? Are there any errors in LogCat or any crashes?

Answer (score 1):

I think this will give you the length of the file to be streamed. After the declaring the MediaPlayer mp object

```
 mp.start();
 totalDur=mp.getDuration();//will give you the duration in milliseconds.
```

For further reference please go through the following link: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#getDuration%28%29

Comment: @Gaurav Gupta: Please also go through the following link to stream the audio file. In that they have mentioned how to get the length of the file to be streamed: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html

Answer (score 0):

with below code you can get duration without using any library

```
player = new MediaPlayer();
player.setDataSource(YOUR_URL);
player.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
player.prepareAsync();

        player.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
                seekBar.setMax(mediaPlayer.getDuration());
                player.start();
            }
        });
```