# How to retrieve MP3 file duration(secs) in android sdk <10

Tags: android

I have stored set of MP3 files  in my sd card. Now I want to retrieve its duration in seconds. I went through few links and I was able to find solution only from SDK version 10 using the `MediaMetadataRetriever` class. But my requirement is for SDk version 7. Is there any way to find out the duration of mp3 files. I am sorry if this is a repeated question here.

I know that using MediaPlayer's `getDuration()` solves this issue. But I don't want to use this.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you have enough data to query the EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI? With the title, for instance, you could do the following:

```
Cursor cursor= getContentResolver().query(android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,null,android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE+"=='Hallelujah'",null,null);
cursor.moveToFirst();
int duration=cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.DURATION));
```

Comment: Will you tell why you dont want to use getDuration() method

Comment: bcoz i am using this data to list the media files. so i wud like to display it with duration also.

Answer (score 0):

```
This will Give the mp3 file duration and file size
String mediaURL = "http://downloads.hussainiat.com/nauhey/arsalan_haider/vol_2011_-_12/01_tum_jawab_e_zulm_dogay_-_arsalan_haider_2011_-_2012.mp3";
    MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();
    mp.setDataSource(mediaURL);
    mp.prepare();
    System.out.println("Duration in ms     " + mp.getDuration());
    URL myUrl = new URL(mediaURL);
    URLConnection urlConnection = myUrl.openConnection();
    urlConnection.connect();
    int file_size = urlConnection.getContentLength();
    System.out.println("FileSize in Bytes    "+ file_size);
```

Comment: getDuration() should be called after onPrepared() is received. I often get 0 miliseconds duration when called getDuration() just after prepare() - not onPrepared()!